# why function returns a list with only one member?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function like this

```
def party_generator(size=1, chars=string.ascii_uppercase):
    parties = []
    for y in range(2):
        party = ''.join(random.choice(chars) for x in range(size))
        parties.append(''.join(['Party ',party]))
        return parties
```

Executing it gives me

```
>>> parties = party_generator()
>>> parties
['Party Z']
```

How do i make it return a list with 2 members ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your indentation puts the `return` *inside* the `for` loop, so it happens on the first iteration. Move it out:

```
def party_generator(size=1, chars=string.ascii_uppercase):
    parties = []
    for y in range(2):
        party = ''.join(random.choice(chars) for x in range(size))
        parties.append(''.join(['Party ',party]))
    return parties
```

Indentation is important in Python!

Comment: Ohh Brilliant catch jon :)